# GoogleSheets - How to look up an updating range of data and cross check values against another dataset

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table ([link to actual googlesheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Peb9hRA440a-oyJYRWGIg-7UoFDPLqFLqzPOF7R_UJw/edit#gid=0)) as seen below which shows customers billing information. First the deposit amount and date it will be paid (blue headings). Then the recurring amount, the amount of recurring payments and each associated date (green headings).

[image]

I have another sheet with scrapes my invoices and populates automatically each payment received. For example:

[image]

I want to be able to cross check the actual amounts paid and the payment dates on sheet 2 and turn the dates green on sheet if the payment amount is correct and the date is within 4 days of next due date.

I'm trying to create a helper table as seen in sheet3 which is created using vlookups but finding it difficult to scope out properly. Should I be using a better function?

Comment: so you want to color the rowfor Cust1 if Cust1 already finished all his payments?

Comment: Yes correct, and the customer can be 4 days late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste this in **M2** cell and drag to the right to reach **Q2** cell. then select **M2:Q2** and drag down. hide whole column or change font color if you wish so). then you can set up simple conditional formatting for each column (**G**, **H**, **I**, **J**, **K**) twice - for two colors (green for "on-time" and red for "late")...

```
=IF(LEN(G2),IF(G2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2,QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C,"select B where A='"&$A2&"'",0),1,0),),"1",
 IF(G2+1=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2+1,QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C,"select B where A='"&$A2&"'",0),1,0),),"2",
 IF(G2+2=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2+2,QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C,"select B where A='"&$A2&"'",0),1,0),),"2",
 IF(G2+3=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2+3,QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C,"select B where A='"&$A2&"'",0),1,0),),"2",
 IF(G2+4=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G2+4,QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C,"select B where A='"&$A2&"'",0),1,0),),"2","0"))))),)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

paste this in **M2** cell and drag down (you can, of course, hide whole column or change font color if you wish so). then you can set up simple conditional formatting...

```
=IF(QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C, "select sum(C) where A='"&A2&"' group by A label sum(C)''", 0)>=
    C2+(E2*F2), 1, 0)*
 IF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(F2:K2), "select Col1 order by Col1 desc limit 1", 0)+4<=
    QUERY(Payments!$A$2:$C, "select B where A='"&A2&"' order by B desc limit 1", 0), 1, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow I had no idea about query functions. Thats pretty awesome! Thanks so much

Comment: Sorry I think I mislead with the last comment I made. I want to color each date green if the corresponding payment has been made. So colour it one by one then go red if the current date is +4 days past any due date

Comment: @NeverPhased this gets confusing... so you want to color only individual dates and differentiate if customer paying on time or he is behind payments?

Comment: Yeh exactly. I tried creating a helper sheet, but its getting pretty complicated